# Color nodes differently and remove label in visNetwork

Tags: r, visnetwork

Trying to visualize a network in R, I have an edges and nodes list. Nodes list looks like this - "id", "label"  and "type":

[image: nodes]

I would like to color the nodes according to their type. So far I tried this by embedding the if statement, but this does not seem to work.

```
visNetwork(nodes, edges) %>% 
  visIgraphLayout(layout = "layout_in_circle") %>% 
  visNodes(label = NULL,(
    if (nodes$type ="gimn") { 
      color= "slategrey"
    } else if (nodes$type ="szakgimn") {
      color="pink"
    } else if  (nodes$type ="ált_isk") {
      color="black"
    } else {
      color ="tomato"
    })) %>% 
  visEdges(arrows = "middle")
```

How to assign color to the nodes according to their type? Also how to remove labels from the plot? (The code above did not seem to work for that either.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you can try a nested `ifelse` to define colors based on type like below

```
visNetwork(nodes, edges) %>%
  visIgraphLayout(layout = "layout_in_circle") %>%
  visNodes(
    label = NULL,
    color = ifelse(nodes$type == "gimn",
      "slategrey",
      ifelse(nodes$type == "szakgimn",
        "pink",
        ifelse(nodes$type == "alt_isk",
          "black", "tomato"
        )
      )
    )
  ) %>%
  visEdges(arrows = "middle")
```

---

Another way is to add `color` to `nodes` before using pipes, e.g.,

```
nodes$color <- ifelse(nodes$type == "gimn",
          "slategrey",
          ifelse(nodes$type == "szakgimn",
            "pink",
            ifelse(nodes$type == "alt_isk",
              "black", "tomato"
            )
          )
        )
visNetwork(nodes, edges) %>%
      visIgraphLayout(layout = "layout_in_circle") %>%
      visEdges(arrows = "middle")
```

Comment: Hm, for same reason, the color of the nodes remains the default color, even when using ifelse.Maybe something wrong with the order of the pipes. Anyway, thanks !

Comment: @cvr I guess you can try to add the `color` column in `nodes` using the nested `ifelse`, then no need to use `visNodes` in pipes